# How to find the course name with minimum students selected

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to find the course name with minimum students selected?

I really appreciate any help.

SQL schema:

```
Create table If Not Exists courses (student varchar(255), class varchar(255))
Truncate table courses
insert into courses (student, class) values ('A', 'Math')
insert into courses (student, class) values ('B', 'English')
insert into courses (student, class) values ('C', 'Math')
insert into courses (student, class) values ('D', 'Biology')
insert into courses (student, class) values ('E', 'Math')
insert into courses (student, class) values ('F', 'Computer')
insert into courses (student, class) values ('G', 'Math')
insert into courses (student, class) values ('H', 'Math')
insert into courses (student, class) values ('I', 'Math')
```

the table:

```
+---------+------------+
| student | class      |
+---------+------------+
| A       | Math       |
| B       | English    |
| C       | Math       |
| D       | Biology    |
| E       | Math       |
| F       | Computer   |
| G       | Math       |
| H       | Math       |
| I       | Math       |
+---------+------------+
```

Should output:

```
+---------+
| class   |
+---------+
| English |
+---------+
| Biology |
+---------+
| Computer|
+---------+
```

Comment: Define "minimum students selected" please.

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this by using the `HAVING` clause:

```sql
SELECT 
  class
FROM 
  courses  
GROUP BY 
  class
HAVING 
  COUNT(*)=(
    SELECT 
      COUNT(*)
    FROM 
      courses  
    GROUP BY 
      class
    ORDER BY 
      COUNT(*) ASC
    LIMIT 1
  )
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is:

- In the select field, use the "count" function to count the number of students
- Since you need to group them by class, use "group by" statement with the class column
- You need the class with the lower number of students, so sort all the results with "order by"

The actual query will be more of less like this:

```
select count(student) as cant_student, class 
from #courses 
group by class 
order by cant_student
```

I did it using SQL server, but the idea is the same in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

You can build a query like this:

- group the class names and count them
- get the number with the least count
- group the class names and count them again, but filter them by the number calculated before

The resulting query might look like this:

```
SELECT
    class,
    COUNT(*) as num
FROM
    courses
GROUP BY
    class
HAVING
    num = (
              SELECT 
                  num
              FROM
                  (
                      SELECT
                          class,
                          COUNT(*) as num
                      FROM
                          courses
                      GROUP BY
                          class
                      ORDER BY
                          num
                  ) c
              LIMIT 1
          );
```

The result would be:

```
+----------+-----+
| class    | num |
+----------+-----+
| Biology  |   1 |
| Computer |   1 |
| English  |   1 |
+----------+-----+
```